# MySQL - Compare all values in a column and write in another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to create a script that compares one field in the database (has a date stored, it's type is "TEXT" and cannot be changed DATE) to the current server date.

The dates are encoded like this "1380571547", so i need to use `strftime()` to decode them. This field for example, decoded with `strftime` corresponds to this `"Sep-30-2013, 22:05"`

What I need is to compare those fields with the current date, and according to that condition, write something like "Expired" in another field.

To achieve this, I made this block of code:

```
<?php
require("connection.php");

$today = strftime('%b-%d-%Y, %H:%M');
$exp_date = mysql_query("SELECT numbers FROM date");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exp_date))
{
echo (strftime ( '%b-%d-%Y, %H:%M', $row ['numbers'])). "<br />";
}


if ($exp_date < $today) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO date (changed) VALUES ('EXPIRED')";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 echo "ADDED!";

} 

?>
```

However, this code is not working, can someone help me ?

Comment: why can't you do this purely in the database?

Comment: It really frustrates me when people post questions and then don't reply to comments.  I just don't understand.  This code could go like 5 different ways depending on various assumptions.  **What are you trying to do exactly?**  Can you explain what your code is trying to do?  There might be a better way.  Is there a reason you can't use just a single update query?  It looks like an easy fix but I don't know what your actual intentions are.

Comment: Sorry for not replying to your comment, but you were right, a single update query was the best way to do it...

However, now i have a new problem, please check my answer in the bottom of the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all this in a single query:

```
UPDATE `date` set `changed`='Expired' where date(now()) > date(from_unixtime(`numbers`))
```

But this is not what your code is attempting to do. Your second block seems to be inserting the word `Expired` in new rows, rather than updating anything.

Note that the table name `date` should be wrapped in backticks to avoid any possible clash with MySQL keywords

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not my strong point but it looks to me like you condition is doing a comparison on an array,

IE:

```
if ($exp_date < $today) // will always be false.
```

Your code would probably have to look something more like this.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exp_date))
{
   if ($row[0] < $today) 
   {
      $sql = "Update date set changed = VALUE where rowid = rowid";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      echo "ADDED!";
    } 
}
```

having said that i would probably do the comparison and update in SQL using a case statement,

```
Update Date 
     set changed = case when number > ExpiryDate 
                        then "Expired"  
                        else "Current" 
                        end
```

Comment: I think they actually mean to use `$row['numbers']` from the part on top.... I'm not sure, though.  And that insert statement probably isn't what they're after at all......

Comment: Agreed: on the insert statement, could be: on the $rows statement

Comment: I've been getting frustrated at new people lately... it's not good.  I just don't understand why they don't even stick around for clarification.

Comment: This is what _I_ think they want... they want to update the table `date` and for any entry that is older than today, they want to `update set changed = 'EXPIRED' where numbers = {$row['numbers']}` but yeah, it should really be done by an `ID` and I don't know why it can't just be done in a query...  Dunno.  I gotta go home, though.  Sorry I got upset lol.... (it's very frustrating to me!)

Comment: Agreed user623952, I've updated my response, hopefully that's a bit clearer.

Comment: Batch processing in sql is far better than the loop approach i guess you would want to update all records that match a certain condition

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the second block of code with the insert. I would do an update inside the loop. but if your going to do that, it could probably be done in one combined update statement.